# Final product of matrix multiplication in dynamic programming?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming, matrix-multiplication

I'm using dynamic programming to find the optimal order of multiplying matrices.
After calculating the right order, How can I calculate the final product of these matrices?
I mean for example I have these matrices:

```
m = [40,20,30,10,30]
```

The optimal order of multiplying is:

```
((A1(A2A3))A4)
```

How can I use this optimal parenthesis to calculate the final product of ((A1(A2A3))A4)?
(Assume I have the value of A1 - An)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a dict with the matrices, such as `matrices = {'A1': ..., 'A2': ...}`, and these are Numpy arrays, you can modify the string to include `__matmul__` operators `@` and then compute the result with `eval`:

```
import re
import numpy as np

matrices = {f'A{i}': np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2, 2)) for i in range(1, 5)}

equation = '((A1(A2A3))A4)'
equation = re.sub('(?<=[0-9)])(?=[(A])', '@', equation)
result = eval(equation, {}, matrices)
```